# Adding components to the world from a different file in Flutter/Flame Game

Tags: flutter, flame

I have several components to my game that involve layering.  I also plan to have multiple levels, which change where these components are positioned.  I coded the first level into the main game file (not main.dart, but the equivalent of myGame.dart), but now I want to move it into it's own class to change the levels easier.  I have a 5 by 5 grid with a character at the bottom and an apple in the middle.  When I had the level one block code in the myGame.dart file, the apple wouldn't show, but the blocks and character would.  Now that I've moved the block code into a levelOne.dart file, the blocks don't show, but there's the apple and character.  Here is the code after I've moved it into the new file.

myGame.dart:

```
    final character = Character()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (0+4) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*4) + 5 * squareGap,);
      //..position = Vector2(squareGap, squareGap);

    final apple = Apple()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2( squareGap + (0+4) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*2) + 3 * squareGap,);

    //originally all of the lists of blocks in the levelOne.dart file were here, but it got moved to the file and replaced with the following line
    final blocks = LevelOne();

    final world = World()
      ..add(character)
      ..add(apple)
      //originally all of the lists of blocks were in here separately, replaced with the following line
      ..add(blocks);


    add(world);
```

levelOne.dart:

```
class LevelOne extends PositionComponent {
  static const double squareWidth = 1000.0;
  static const double squareHeight = 1000.0;
  static const double squareGap = 175.0;
  static const double squareRadius = 100.0;
  static final Vector2 squareSize = Vector2(squareWidth, squareHeight);

  final blocks5 = List.generate(
    5,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position =
      Vector2((i + 2) * (squareWidth + squareGap) + squareGap, squareGap),
  );
  final blocks4 = List.generate(
    5,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+2) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        squareHeight + 2 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks3P1 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+2) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*2) + 3 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks3P2 = List.generate(
    1,
        (i) => PavementBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+4) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*2) + 3 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks3P3 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+5) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*2) + 3 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks2P1 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+2) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*3) + 4 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks2P2 = List.generate(
    1,
        (i) => PavementBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+4) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*3) + 4 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks2P3 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+5) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*3) + 4 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks1P1 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+2) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*4) + 5 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks1P2 = List.generate(
    1,
        (i) => PavementBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+4) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*4) + 5 * squareGap,),
  );
  final blocks1P3 = List.generate(
    2,
        (i) => GrassBlocks()
      ..size = squareSize
      ..position = Vector2(
        squareGap + (i+5) * (squareWidth + squareGap),
        (squareHeight*4) + 5 * squareGap,),
  );
}
```

I've tried changing the PositionComponent to a SpriteComponent, but as this code doesn't directly contain a Sprite (calls SpriteComponent classes), that didn't work.  How would I get the moved code to show all of the blocks in levelOne.dart, as well as have the apple on top?

Comment: We also have a discord chat where you can ask questions if you feel like it:
https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add components to the world they will be rendered in the order that they are added if the `priority` isn't set. You can think of `priority` as the Z-index in Flame.

So in your case when you do this:

```dart
    final world = World()
      ..add(character)
      ..add(apple)
      //originally all of the lists of blocks were in here separately, replaced with the following line
      ..add(blocks);
```

The `blocks` will be rendered on top of the character and apple, making them not visible. To solve this you can either add the `blocks` first, or you can set the `priority` of `character` and `apple` to something higher than `0` (the default).

The priority can be set either directory in the call to the super constructor:

```dart
class Test extends PositionCompontent {
  Test() : super(priority: 1);
}
```

or it can be changed during runtime with:

```dart
final test = Test();
add(test);
test.priority = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That seems to help when it's all in one file, but the blocks still are not showing when that code got moved to a new file.  Do you know what might help with that?  I gave each item a corresponding priority, but it doesn't seem to make the blocks show up

Comment: It should not make a difference if you have it in the same file or not, I would suggest joining our discord chat so that you can show more of the code. :)
discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4